# Use epsilon-delta definition of limits to show that $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(\sqrt{-x^2-y^2})=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, epsilon-delta

Use epsilon-delta definition of limits to show that

$$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}(\sqrt{-x^2-y^2})=0$$

We need to show that $$\forall \epsilon >0( \exists \delta >0( \forall (x,y) \in \mathbb R^2 (0<\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\delta \implies \left|\sqrt{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}\right|<\epsilon)))$$

If $0<\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}<\delta$ then $\sqrt{-(x^{2}+y^{2})}<0<\delta$

So I think if $\delta \le \epsilon$ then the claim does hold,is that true?

Comment: The expression  $-(x^2+y^2)<0$ for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.

Comment: $\;\sqrt{-x^2-y^2}\;$ on the reals is defined only at $\;(x,y)=(0,0)\;$ ...pretty boring.

Comment: @masheb you can't define that function on $\mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$ because the square root is not well defined there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to be careful with the definition of limits in this case. The function
$$
f(x,y)=\sqrt{-x^2-y^2}
$$
is only defined on the set $E=\{(0,0)\}$.

So the notion of limits must be restricted to the (trivial) metric subspace $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

In the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of your limit, you should have

> for every $\epsilon$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that the condition $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ **and** $(x,y)\in E$ implies that $|f(x,y)|<\epsilon$ .

But this is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) since $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ is never satisfied.

---

Added notes.

In general, let $X$ and $Y$ be two metric spaces and $E\subset X$, $f:E\to Y$. To avoid the vacuously true case, one only defines the notion of limits $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)$ when $p$ is a limit point $E$, meaning that every neighborhood of $p$ contains a point $q\ne p$ such that $q\in E$. (See for instance Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis*.) Your example of $E$ has no limit points.

Comment: "Vacuously true" is the real thing in this exercize! +1

Comment: Isn't it usually required in the definition of limits that the point where you take the limit is an accumulation point of the function's domain? (Just to exclude this vacuously true case.)

Comment: @HansLundmark: Yes. Thanks for your comment. I added a note.